# UITableViewCell is choppy when scrolled for Custom Table View Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, performance, uitableview

I have a tableview that contains 3 different types of uitableview cell. And it is choppy when i scrolled down or up. I have tried many ways to not make it choppy but fail.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    CD_Dates *dates = [self.cdMenuStream.dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    MenuTableViewCell *tCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MenuTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch ([self getRowTypeForIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        case RowTypeMenu:
            [tCell configMenuCell:dates.menu withAnimation:self.switchMenuAnimationFlag];
            break;

        case RowTypeAddon:
            [tCell configAddonCell:dates.addon_menu withAnimation:self.switchMenuAnimationFlag];
            break;

        case RowTypeContent:
            [tCell configContentCell:dates.content];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    tCell.delegate = self;
    tCell.currentIndexPath = indexPath;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        tCell.csMarginTopTitleView.constant = 0;
    }

    [tCell setNeedsDisplay];
    [tCell layoutIfNeeded];
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    cell = tCell;
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat heightRow = 0;

    switch ([self getRowTypeForIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        case RowTypeMenu:
            heightRow = 477.6667;
            break;

        case RowTypeAddon:
            heightRow = 283.6667;
            break;

        case RowTypeContent:
            heightRow = 187.6667;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (heightRow == 0) {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        heightRow = heightRow - 22.5;
    }

    return heightRow;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MenuTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat horizontalOffset = -17.5;
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd %zd", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    if ([self.contentOffsetDictionary valueForKey:key]) {
        horizontalOffset = [self.contentOffsetDictionary[key] floatValue];
    }
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    [cell.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(horizontalOffset, cell.collectionView.contentOffset.y)];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat heightRow = 0;

    switch ([self getRowTypeForIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        case RowTypeMenu:
            heightRow = 477.6667;
            break;

        case RowTypeAddon:
            heightRow = 283.6667;
            break;

        case RowTypeContent:
            heightRow = 187.6667;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (heightRow == 0) {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        heightRow = heightRow - 22.5;
    }

    return heightRow;
}
```

It is a tableview wrapped with a custom tableview cell, and that each custom tableview cell has a collection view. It is not choppy if i scroll the collection view in the custom tableview cell, but it is when i scroll the tableview. Is there any ways we can make it not choppy, thanks.

Comment: is it causing glitches?

Comment: What do you mean by choppy? Screenshot of the problem would help a lot to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with the sizing cell.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Please try with this or share the cell's .xib files so that automatic sizing will be enabled.